# TFS 2015: default value for old workitems

Tags: tfs

TFS 2015.2.1. I have a workitem with custum fields. I have seen that if I set a default value (a new rule for the template) this does not auto-populate pre-existing records.
While new records get the default value, the existing records remain with no value in the new field: if I open the workitem I can see the field 
with the default value populated (also with old records) but this value is saved only when you save the workitem. 
You can see this with a query: if you search workitems with "the default value" you will find only new workitems or old workitems re-opened and re-saved.
Is it possible to save a default value in old records?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested in TFS 2015.3, when apply a default value with DEFAULT rule to a custom field like the example below, the pre-existing records also has this value:

```
<FieldDefinition name="version" refname="version.version" type="String">
  <DEFAULT from="value" value="1.0" />
</FieldDefinition>
```

You may upgrade your TFS to TFS 2015.3, and set a similar rule as my example, your pre-existing records should have the default value too.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Are you sure that the value is saved and not merely displayed when you open a record? I have seen that the old values are not populated. As I said you can see this doing a simple query looking for all the workitems that have the new field set to the default value: it returns nothing. Looking at the changelog of TFS 2015.3 I could not find anything on the following fix.

Comment: Correct, it is only displayed and the value is not written onto the work item.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this "issue" in the past, and your observations are right. Changing rules on a field in the work item template won't affect existing records until you open and save them. Therefore, you'll have to update existing records to populate your new fields with their respective default value.

You may use Excel to mass-edit the existing records and achieve your goal.

Comment: That works for small numbers of work items, but over 10,000 it can get pretty slow.

Comment: I agree. I would use the API in this situation, or when you have too many Team Projects to update.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; I have has this problem before and created a tool to bulk edit work items and fill out the values

### 1-1000 Work Items

Just use the Web Access bulk edit. Multi select in the web, right click, and select Edit.

### 1000-10,000 Work Items

Create a Query and then Open Excel and connect to TFS/VSTS and open the query. Bulk edit from here and publish.

### 10,000+ Work Items

Us the VSTS Sync Migration (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration) tools to bulk edit one or more fields in any number of work items. Use the "UpdateWorkItem" processor with as many "Field Mapps" to make the changes that you need.

Note: There are some inaccuracies in the documentation but if you install with Chocolatey you can use "vstssyncmigrator init" from anywhere.